# autofac resolve all ICommandHandler<ICommand,IMessageResult>

Tags: c#, autofac

Hi In a MessageDispatch Scenario in .Net i register all my command handlers like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(commandsAssemblies)
.AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
.InstancePerRequest();
```

in my OnActivating method for my messageDispatcher i want to register the commandHandlers with the messageDispatcher like this.

```
builder.RegisterType<MessageDispatcher>()
.As<IMessageDispatcher>().InstancePerRequest()
.OnActivating(e =>

{
 var handlers = e.Context.Resolve(IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand,IMessageResult>>);
    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        e.Instance.RegisterCommandHandler(handler);
    }
......
```

A commandHandler is implemented like:

```
public class ActivateCampaignHandler : CommandHandler<ActivateCampaign,MessageResult>   
{
    ....
```

My problem is that the Resolve doesnt work. I Can se that the handler is registered, but only has 2 services it self and ICommandHandler

How do I resolve all my commandhandlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 solutions to retrieve a `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<,>>`.

The easiest one would be to introduce a non generic `ICommandHandler` interface :

```
    public interface ICommandHandler { }
    public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TMessageResult>
        : ICommandHandler
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TMessageResult : IMessageResult
    { }

    // register it this way 
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
            .As<ICommandHandler>();
```

This is the solution I recommend because it may be easier to work with a non generic interface.

The second solution would consist of making your interface covariant (using the `out` modifier) to allow casting from `TestCommandHandler` to `ICommandHandler<ICommand, IMessageResult>` and register your types as `ICommandHandler<ICommand, IMessageResult>`

```
    public interface ICommandHandler<out TCommand, out TMessageResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TMessageResult : IMessageResult
    { }

    // register this way
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>))
            .As<ICommandHandler<ICommand, IMessageResult>>();

    // resolve this ways
    var commandHandlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand, IMessageResult>>>();
    Console.WriteLine(commandHandlers.Count());
```

The latest solution would be to create your own `IRegistrationSource` it requires more work but it will avoid registering your types as `ICommandHandler<ICommand, IMessageResult>` and will allow you to resolve things like that `ICommandHandler<ISpecificCommand, IMessageResult>` (if you `IRegistrationSource` implementation allows that of course).

You can have a look at the [`ContravariantRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/Variance/ContravariantRegistrationSource.cs) to see how to make yours.

Comment: Very intelligent and qualified answer indeed. One problem is that TCommand is used as a parameter in  an Execute Method. So i Guess it cannot be declared covariant. Im currently going with the simple ICommandHandler solution and use interfaces rather than generic types. I Then have to cast from interface ICommand to TCommand, which I would like to get rid of. But I will try to mark Your answer as being the correct solution.