# AutoFac Resolve CommandHandlers from specific derived services

Tags: c#, autofac

Note:  This is similar to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969289/autofac-resolve-all-icommandhandlericommand-imessageresult)

My Question is if I have interfaces defined like below:

*(NOTE:  My code has more than one derived level; example for simplicity)*

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle(IBaseCommand command);
}

public interface IHandler<out T> : IHandler where T : IBaseCommand { }

public interface IBaseCommand { }
public interface IDerivedCommand : IBaseCommand { }
public class BaseCommand : IBaseCommand { }
public class DerivedCommand : IDerivedCommand { }

public class BaseCommandHandler : IHandler<IBaseCommand>
{
    public void Handle(IBaseCommand command) { }
}

public class DerivedCommandHandler : IHandler<IDerivedCommand>
{
    public void Handle(IBaseCommand command) { }
    public void Handle(IDerivedCommand command) { }
}
```

My snippet of registrations for this example looks like:

```
builder.RegisterType<DerivedCommand>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<BaseCommand>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<DerivedCommandHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<BaseCommandHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<IBaseCommand>>>();` only returns `BaseCommandHandler`.

I need to get `BaseCommandHandler` and all derived types, which in this instance would include `DerivedCommandHandler` too.

I realize this registration `container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler>>();` will resolve **ALL** handlers but I need to be able to resolve any where in the derived chain.

QUESTION:  How do I resolve all handlers starting from a specific derived service?

Comment: Why do you need to resolvr all handlers? Do you wish to execute all of them? And if so, why does a single command have multiple handlers? That would be weird. Or do you simply wish to dispatch an incomming command to one particular handler and are you looping through the list to get the particular handler?

Comment: Apologies.  I had refactored by naming and forgot to update my class/interface names.  Edited to reflect above.

1 command for 1 handler.  I wish to dispatch based on the resolved type so I do not have to resolve all.  For instance, if I resolve IHandler<ISomeCommand>, it return all handlers that are of ISomeCommand and any handlers that have commands other interfaces derived from ISomeCommand.

Comment: If I keep it covariant, I have found this works but I need to know all the registrations upfront which I guess I can figure out through reflection.

`builder.RegisterType<DerivedCommandHandler>().As<IHandler<IBaseCommand>>().As<IHandler<IDerivedCommand>>();`

Answer (score 0):

You chould change this:

```
IHandler<out T>
```

to:

```
IHandler<in T>
```

Comment: That's true.  Would that help me get all handlers from the derived type?

Comment: Have you tried it? I do believe that Autofac has some sort of support for variance.

Comment: I did but got the same results.  So far, my solution has been to call the non-generic handler which resolves all of them and then use if statements.

`if (handler is IHandler<IBaseCommand>)`
`else if (handler is IHandler<IDerviedCommand>)`

Comment: The irony of this all is that your handlers have an input parameter, but that makes them contravariant, which means that you can only resolve less specific versions if you request a specific version. In other words, if you can resolve `IEnumerable<IHandler<SubType>>` and that list might also contain `IHandler<BaseType>`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Autofac has variance support, but you have to explicitly enable it with `builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());`